# Is there anyway to get the every detail infomation of new updating of Chrome Extension API in time?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I need to catch every little update infomation of Chrome Extension API, but i find no place to provide news or list to get these.

Is there any way to catch these infomation in time?

Comment: You can make a new git repository, update it from the [official types package](https://unpkg.com/browse/chrome-types/_all.d.ts) and do a git diff and do it automatically by writing a script and run it on schedule.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it was very helpful to me.